# Extract databases, schemas, tables, and column names from SQL scripts

Tags: sql, text-extraction, information-extraction

I need to create a spreadsheet listing the database, schema, table, and column name for every field from ~100 SQL scripts. Is there a way in SQL, Python or R to do this? I am currently attempting to do this with string extraction in Python.

The spreadsheet needs to look something like this:

| database | schema | table | column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| database1 | schema1 | table1 | id |
| database1 | schema1 | table1 | name |
| database1 | schema2 | table2 | id |
| database1 | schema2 | table2 | address |
| database2 | schema3 | table3 | id |
| database2 | schema3 | table3 | score |
| database2 | schema3 | table4 | id |
| database2 | schema3 | table4 | gender |

The spreadsheet needs to include all fields that appear in a table or are used in building a table but not including in the output.

- in the SELECT statement
- used to filter the data in a WHERE or a JOIN
- used to calculate another field but is not included in the SELECT statement
- used in any other manner

The SQL scripts frequently create temporary data sets for intermediate calculation. The scripts were written by several authors; there is a lack of consistency between coding styles. The intermediate tables and inconsistent styles are making accurate string extraction difficult.

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` might be a good option

Answer (score 1):

There is no utility that I know of that will do this for random SQL scripts.

You could compile the scripts and then check their Dependencies in the database catalogs.  The problem is this doesn't always catch everything (like dynamic SQL) and generally it won't tell you the columns (both of these vary by DBMS however).

If I had to do this, here's how I might do it:

1. Make a copy of the database the scripts were intended to work on.
2. Write DDL trigger(s) that will capture every metadata change and report it in a standard way.
3. Write generic DML triggers that will capture the affected table and columns of every data change and then write a dynamic SQL procedure that will copy them onto every table.
4. Run the scripts against my copy of the database.
5. Collect the trigger's output, then put that into Excel.

Even with all this, it would still miss stuff (because of `IF..` statements)

Offhand I'd estimate that this would take me about 2-4 weeks (your mileage may vary), so I'd compare that against how long it would take me to just read every script and manually enter the data into Excel.

In the end, I'd probably do it manually.

---

A couple of more options from the comments:

Write your own tool to *Parse the scripts* for you:  This is much harder than it sounds at first, SQL is crazy hard to parse, but if your DBMS has a facility to parse SQL scripts and then provide you with the Parse Tree, this might work (I don't know which, if any, DBMS's might have this).

If this script is intended to *Create a Database* from scratch, then it's easy:  just run it and then collect the schema, tables and column names from the system catalogs.

Comment: I'm not sure you need all this.  Just search the scripts for  CREATE TABLE statements and parse those.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A) Parsing CREATE TABLE is a helluva job, it's the most complex statement in all of SQL, and 2) This only works if the collected scripts are intended to create a new database.  If they are intended to modify an existing one, it won't work.  And if they are intended to create a SQL database, then you can just read the metadata from the system catalogs, that's *far* easier than any of the other options.

Comment: I left a comment on the OP.  Without more information about the OP's problem, speculation about the possible solution to their problem seems pointless.

Comment: There are too many subtleties and edge cases: It would be faster and more accurate/complete to just spend a few hours eyeballing the scripts and collating the results by hand.

Comment: @Bohemian  There's ~100 scripts, depending on how big and complicated each is, it might be faster 9and more reliable) to use one of the other ways.  Also, dynamic SQL can be notoriously hard to read, you can't really just "eyeball" it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung but you *must* read it. Consider `"select " + colNameVariable + " from " + tableNameVariable`. You would have to write a parser for the script language, and a simulated runtime for it to know the values of variables, then write code the extract the schema for the column type. It would take a while to manually do it, but I guarantee it would take days/weeks to write code to do it.

Comment: @Bohemian Writing code to parse it is not what I recommended.  I did include it as a possibility, but IMHO, it's the least desirable method.